# No vibration during NSU application

Tags: update

After updating the Windows 10 on mylumia 1320, the phone could not restart. It only display the word NOKIA. I then tried the Nokia Software Updater for Retail version 4.3.2. However, if i simultaneously press the Power and Volume buttons, the phone does not vibrate, when running NSU. How do I go about this issue?